# Configure build machine memory with kotlin compile daemon, gradle daemons in parallel

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, gradle, continuous-integration

Assuming we have the following setup of a build machine:
24 cores.
16 GB ram.
Kotlin version: `1.5.30`

I'd like to compile sources and find a stable configuration to avoid OOM errors and keep an optimal speed

For example in android it could be `:app:assembleDebug` task which performs compilation and builds an apk

Kotlin has own [build daemon](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#kotlin-daemon-and-using-it-with-gradle) which runs together with a gradle daemon.
We should use `--parallel` flag for decoupled projects to speed up a build.

And here the trickiest part is how to split available RAM between parallel gradle workers and kotlin daemons to **prevent** OOM.

Which value should be used in `org.gradle.jvmargs` and `kotlin.daemon.jvm.options` with `--max-workers=3` for example?

Like we may give for kotlin daemon **4G** with `kotlin.daemon.jvm.options=-Xmx4G`, should we set gradle workers configuration as `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx12G` for our build machine or **12G/3**: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4G`?

Can multiply kotlin daemons be created and, as a result, exceed memory constraints?